# How can I pick the best matching pattern(haplotype) to my data? Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, bioinformatics

I am working on a pharmacogenetic profiler for my internship.
For this profiler I need to identify the most likely haplotypes a patient has.
What I have so far:

Haplotype definitions from a database, containing the following:

- Haplotype Name
- a list of alleles/SNPs that make up the haplotype
- *separately - The location (chromosome, start, stop) for each allele/SNP

It looks a bit like:

```
...
['UGT1A1*16', 'T;A;T;C;G;A;G;C']
['UGT1A1*17', 'T;A;T;C>T;G;A;G;C']
...
```

with each allele(e.g. each A, T, C or G) having a location like:
    `[6, 18130687, 18130687]` which represents `[chromosome, start, stop]` and for example `C>G` meaning that the reference position is a C, but the difference for this haplotype definition is that it is a G instead of C.

I then checked all those locations, to see which alleles the patient has at those positions. Since a person has two alleles for each location, I obtain something like the following:

```
UGT1A1 = ['T-T', 'A-A', 'T-T', 'C-T', 'C-G', 'A-A', 'G-G','C-C']
```

The format is: `'<allele_1>-<allele_2>'` and allele_1 and allele_2 can be interchanged with each other. (I do not know which alleles belong together, since I don't have phasing information)

Now I need to match the alleles I observed in the patients in the most optimal way. Each allele in each pair has to be used, and can only be used once each. In my example, I have different alleles in the 4th and 5th pair `'C-T' and 'C-G'` and could thus create 4 different haplotypes like:

```
[T, A, T, C, C, A, G, C]
[T, A, T, C, G, A, G, C]
[T, A, T, T, C, A, G, C]
[T, A, T, T, G, A, G, C] <-- the same as UGT1A1*17
```

Say I would now choose one set of alleles to be `TATTGAGC`, the other will have to be `TATCCAGC`. The first being the same as the haplotype for UGT1A1*17, but the other having "only" 7 out of 8 alleles overlap with any other haplotype.
The actual dataset is a lot larger, and the haplotype allele length can be over 200 alleles long, plus have between 10 and and 100 different definitions and last but not least, there are about 60 different genes (with each those haplotype definitions again).

So is there an efficient way of obtaining all the allele combinations that make up the haplotypes with allowing the least amount of mismatches?

Hints of how to do it are welcome to, as in; Use dicts in a way like ... or dump certain information in a sql database (to save memory, whilst working on the data) or other things like it.

Thanks for taking your time to read through all this!

Comment: Are you asking the most efficient of generating the four combinations (i know it's more) from this list `['T-T', 'A-A', 'T-T', 'C-T', 'C-G', 'A-A', 'G-G','C-C']`? Do you need to filter the elements of that list in some way and you want the most efficient way to filter them?

Comment: I would say both, although I was hoping for a good third strategy, which i haven't thought about myself yet.

Comment: are you looking for something like `itertools.product`?  `list(itertools.product('a', 'bc', 'de'))` will output `[('a', 'c', 'd'), ('a', 'c', 'e'), ('b', 'c', 'd'), ('b', 'c', 'e')]`

Answer (score 0):

It is not completely clear what you're asking, but hopefully this sets you on the right track.

Expanding on [the comment by e.s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50115755/how-can-i-pick-the-best-matching-patternhaplotype-to-my-data-python-2-7#comment87256929_50115755)., but with a helper function to make the code clearer, the way to generate all haplotypes is:

```
from itertools import product

alleles = ['T-T', 'A-A', 'T-T', 'C-T', 'C-G', 'A-A', 'G-G','C-C']

def normalize(pair):
    a, b = pair.split('-')
    if a == b:
        return a
    else:
        return a + b

normalized_alleles = [normalize(pair) for pair in alleles]
for haplotype in product(*normalized_alleles):
    print(haplotype)
```

This prints:

```
('T', 'A', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'C')
('T', 'A', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'C')
('T', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'C')
('T', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'C')
```

It is unclear what you mean with 'obtaining all the allele combinations that make up the haplotypes with allowing the least amount of mismatches', so I can't tell if this is the most efficient way.

Comment: What I want to obtain is the best fitting haplotypes to my patient data. In whichever way. But since the data is quite large as usual, using the cartesian procuct will probably take up too much memory and time.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a complete solution, but here's a general outline of the steps I would take to solve this:

Most people are suggesting ways to create all possible combinations of alleles, but this isn't really going to help you to figure out which haplotypes best match your alleles. What I would suggest is making a list of all possible pairs of *reference haplotypes* then mapping your alleles to each of these pairs and taking the best pair. It should be easy enough to go though the SNPs and assign a score based on how many of the alleles at that position match the pair of haplotypes, ie; if both haplotypes have `A` at a position, `A/A` would match both, while `A/C` would only match one. Sum across SNPs for each haplotype pair, take the highest scoring pair, and you're done.